# Running two for loops with different intervals simultaneously in one function

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

b, c = filter_list(a)

b = [1, 3, 4, 5]
c = [2, 6, 7, 8,9]
```

Given list `a` that gets filtered by features of the elements of that list( not-relevant) and put into two different lists `a, b` through function `filter_list` .

```
def print_all_loop(number_list, repetition, seconds=5):
    for x in range(0, repetition):
        for i in range(len(number_list)):
            print(number_list[i])
        sleep(seconds)
```

The function above takes a `numbers_list`(`b OR c`), prints every element, sleeps a given amount(`seconds`)  and repeats this a given amount of times(`repetition`).

Now I want to make a function that can take two lists (`b AND c`) and make it sleep different amounts.

The function should loop over (printing in this case all elements) both list `b` and `c` but over `b` every 1min and over `c` every 15min

Output of `b` every 1min and `c` every 15min should be:

```
min
1 print b [1, 3, 4, 5] and print c [2, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2 print b
3 print b
4 print b
5 print b
6 print b
7 print b
8 print b
9 print b
10 print b
11 print b
12 print b
13 print b
14 print b
15 print b [1, 3, 4, 5] and print c [2, 6, 7, 8, 9]
16 print b
```

Is there any other way to do this efficiently besides threading? As I would rather not use that.

Thanks in advance! If any more details are needed do ask.

Comment: One solution is to just make your function asynchronous and call it for each list.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```py
import asyncio


async def print_all(some_list, times, delay=5):
    for _ in range(times):
        for item in some_list:
            print(item)
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)


async def loop_lists(a, b, delay_a, delay_b, times):
    await asyncio.gather(
        print_all(a, times, delay_a),
        print_all(b, times, delay_b)
    )


async def main():
    a = [1, 3, 4, 5]
    b = ["x", "y", "z"]
    await loop_lists(a, b, 2, 1, 5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

[`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) runs the passed awaitables concurrently. Note that for this to work, you must use the [`asyncio.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) function instead of the `time.sleep` function. This is because you **need** a point where the event loop can switch contexts, i.e. stop executing one coroutine and hop to another.

**PS:**

You could even generalize `loop_lists` to accept an arbitrary number of list-delay-pairs like so:

```py
async def loop_lists(*list_delay_pairs, times):
    await asyncio.gather(
        *(print_all(lst, times, delay) for lst, delay in list_delay_pairs)
    )
```

And then call it like this:

```py
async def main():
    a = [1, 3, 4, 5]
    b = ["x", "y", "z"]
    await loop_lists((a, 2), (b, 1), times=5)
```